# codigo generico para construção de queries mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Bom, eu estou precisando construir um código genérico que construa uma query mysql, desejo descobrir a melhor maneira de fazê-lo.
Através de um JSON eu enviarei as informações, são elas:

```
"Group"(TAG, EMPRESA, CARRO);
"Group_value"(id's das tags, empresas, carros);
"Function"(INSERT, REMOVE, DELETE);
"Condition"(seria o meu WHERE).
```

No momento estou reconhecendo o grupo e através de um switch case defino a tabela e coluna que serão editadas, e a coluna que será aplicado o where.

Quando a "function" é DELETE a única coisa que é possível fazer é deletar os clientes selecionados, logo não tenho grandes problemas com essa condição.

Segue código de rascunho:

```
function (event, context) => {
var table, column, condition;

switch (event.group) {
    case 'Tags':
        table = 'client_tags'
        column = 'client_tag_id'
        condition = 'client_id'
        break;
    case 'Cars':
        table =  'clients'
        column = 'car_id'
        condition = 'id'
        break;
    case 'Empresas':
        table = 'clients'
        column = 'company_id'
        condition = 'id'
        break;
    // default:
    // 
}

var query = "UPDATE " +table+ " SET " +column+ " = " +event.group_values_id+ " WHERE " +condition+ " = " +event.condition



return query
};
```

Basicamente o Update está construído da maneira certa, porém quando o grupo é TAG serão aplicados DELETE ou INSERT, sendo que existe a possibilidade de um cliente ter várias tags, (Tags tem uma tabela a parte ligada a Clients através de chave estrangeira, já EMPRESAS e CARROS são colunas na tabela clients).

Gostaria de um norte para construir o melhor código que tratará essas condições!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao construir instruções SQL dinamicamente, uma de suas primeiras preocupações deve ser a segurança, pois são comuns os ataques do tipo [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL). Se as queries serão geradas apenas *server-side*, o problema se torna menor (desde que o aplicativo cliente não passe trechos da query, apenas parâmetros para a mesma). Caso exista uma quantia pequena de operações a serem realizadas, queries pré-definidas pode ser uma abordagem mais segura que a geração dinâmica.

A respeito da implementação que você explicou, operações básicas [CRUD](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) (Create, Read, Update, Delete) são suportadas pela maioria dos frameworks disponíveis. Recomendo utilizar algum (como [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) ou [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)) para abstrair a implementação dessas operações e focar no desenvolvimento das regras de negócio mais complexas para sua aplicação.

Para montagem das queries per se, sugiro utilizar uma biblioteca como a [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) ou [Doctrine ORM Query Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/query-builder.html#the-querybuilder). Uma delas, aliada à uma boa arquitetura do seu arquivo de query (JSON) deve ser uma boa solução para o problema.

Comment: Obrigado, seu comentário foi de grande ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

O comentário do Mathias foi de grande ajuda!

Acabei substituindo o switch case por um objeto do tiopo const

```
    const GROUPS = {
    TAGS: {
        table: "client_tags",
        column: "client_tag_id",
        condition: "client_id"
    },
    CARS: {
        table: "clients",
        column: "car_id",
        condition: "id"           
    },
    COMPANIES: {
        table: "clients",
        column: "company_id",
        condition: "id"           
    }
}
```

e logo após atribuo a variável GROUP o resultado da verificação

```
const GROUP = GROUPS[event.group]
```

Por fim utilizei o Knex para construir minhas consultas, deixando o código mais limpo, e a única verificação que faço é se o event.group = Tags.